# Tooltipster popup and php switch cases

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to improve the user experience of a web page by moving all functions that would normally require a page reload into ajax popups. I've been successful on all but one function.
I took the original php file and call it via AJAX in an interactive tooltip. The issue I have is that this file has a number of buttons that when clicked select a specific case in a php switch statement.

An example of the html behind one of the original buttons would be

```
<a href="http://localhost/devarea/devadmin/image_handler.php?products_filter=313&amp;action=layout_edit"><img src="includes/languages/english/images/buttons/button_edit.gif" border="0" alt="IH_IMAGE_EDIT" title=" IH_IMAGE_EDIT "></a>
```

which would then invoke

```
case 'layout_edit':
                // Edit specific details 
                $imgNameStr = '&amp;imgEdit=1' . '&amp;imgBase=' . $products_image_base
                                               . "&amp;imgSuffix=" . $selected_image_suffix
                                               . "&amp;imgBaseDir=" . $products_image_directory 
                                               . "&amp;imgExtension=" . $selected_image_extension;
                $heading[] = array(
                    'text' => '<strong>' . TEXT_INFO_EDIT_PHOTO . '</strong>'
                );
.... //more code in here
break;
```

What I'm hoping to do is use AJAX, jQuery, or Javascript to call the relevant case when a button is clicked, saving the current content of the displayed div, displaying the content generated by the case, and then restore the original content once processed. I would prefer the solution not to require moving the content of every switch case to a new file if possible.

Whilst I know how to save the current content and restore it, I have no idea if I can even do what I want with the switch cases.

Is this something that's even possible with AJAX, jQuery, or Javascript?
Some pointers to useful resources and reading would be really helpful as my search on Google hasn't turned up anything of use yet.

Added the entire switch as requested by ArtisiticPhoenix

```
switch ($action) {
            case 'layout_edit':
                // Edit specific details 
                $imgNameStr = '&amp;imgEdit=1' . '&amp;imgBase=' . $products_image_base
                                               . "&amp;imgSuffix=" . $selected_image_suffix
                                               . "&amp;imgBaseDir=" . $products_image_directory 
                                               . "&amp;imgExtension=" . $selected_image_extension;
                $heading[] = array(
                    'text' => '<strong>' . TEXT_INFO_EDIT_PHOTO . '</strong>'
                );

            case 'layout_new':  
                if ( $action != 'layout_edit' ) {
                    $imgNameStr .= ( $no_images ) ? "&amp;newImg=1" : '&amp;imgBase='.$products_image_base
                                                                    . "&amp;imgBaseDir=" . $products_image_directory 
                                                                    . "&amp;imgExtension=" . $default_extension;
                    $heading[] = array(
                        'text' => '<strong>' . TEXT_INFO_NEW_PHOTO . '</strong>'
                    );
                }

                $contents = array(
                    'form' => zen_draw_form('image_define', FILENAME_IMAGE_HANDLER, 
                                            '&products_filter=' . $products_filter . $imgNameStr
                                          . '&amp;action=save', 'post', 'enctype="multipart/form-data"')
                ); //steve check this &products_filter=

                // check if this is a master image or if no images exist
                if ($no_images) {
                    $contents[] = array(
                        'text' => '<strong>' . TEXT_INFO_IMAGE_BASE_NAME . '</strong><br />' 
                    );
                    $contents[] = array(
                        'text' => zen_draw_input_field('imgBase', '', 'size="30"')
                    );

                    $dir = @dir(DIR_FS_CATALOG_IMAGES);
                    $dir_info[] = array('id' => '', 'text' => TEXT_INFO_MAIN_DIR);
                    while ($file = $dir->read()) {
                        if (is_dir(DIR_FS_CATALOG_IMAGES . $file) 
                            && strtoupper($file) != 'CVS' 
                            && $file != "." 
                            && $file != ".." 
                            && $file != 'original' 
                            && $file != 'medium'
                            && $file != 'large') {
                            $dir_info[] = array('id' => $file . '/', 'text' => $file);
                        }
                    }
                    $contents[] = array('
                        text' => '<br /><strong>' . TEXT_INFO_BASE_DIR . '</strong><br />' . TEXT_INFO_NEW_DIR
                    );
                    $contents[] = array(
                        'text' => TEXT_INFO_IMAGE_DIR . zen_draw_pull_down_menu('imgBaseDir', $dir_info, "")
                    );
                    $contents[] = array(
                        'text' => TEXT_INFO_OR.' ' . zen_draw_input_field('imgNewBaseDir', '', 'size="20"') 
                    );
                } else if ($action != 'layout_edit') {
                    $contents[] = array(
                        'text' => '<strong>' . TEXT_INFO_IMAGE_SUFFIX . '</strong><br />' . TEXT_INFO_USE_AUTO_SUFFIX . '<br />' 
                    );
                    $contents[] = array(
                        'text' => zen_draw_input_field('imgSuffix', $selected_image_suffix, 'size="10"') 
                    );
                }

                // -----
                // Set up the "acceptable" file types for the form, depending on whether or not the active product
                // currently has an image defined.
                //
                if ($no_images) {
                    $accept = 'image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/gif,image/png';
                } else {
                    switch (strtolower($products_image_extension)) {
                        case '.gif':
                            $accept = 'image/gif';
                            break;
                        case '.png':
                            $accept = 'image/png';
                            break;
                        case '.jpg':        //-Fall-through ...
                        case '.jpeg':
                            $accept = 'image/jpeg,image/jpg';
                            break;
                        default:
                            $accept = 'image/jpeg,/image/jpg,image/gif,image/png';
                            break;
                    }
                }
                $file_parms = 'accept="' . $accept . '"';

                // Image fields
                if ( $action == 'layout_new' ) {// display warning on edit screen that the default file must be filled in
                    //-------------------------
                    $contents[] = array(
                        'text' => '<br /><strong>' . TEXT_INFO_DEFAULT_IMAGE . '</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong class="errorText">(required)</strong><br />' 
                            . TEXT_INFO_DEFAULT_IMAGE_HELP . '<br />'
                            . zen_draw_input_field('default_image', '', 'size="20" ' . $file_parms, false, 'file') . '<br />' . $pInfo->products_image
                    );
                } else {
                    $contents[] = array(
                        'text' => '<br /><strong>' . TEXT_INFO_DEFAULT_IMAGE . '</strong><br />' 
                            . TEXT_INFO_DEFAULT_IMAGE_HELP . '<br />'
                            . zen_draw_input_field('default_image', '', 'size="20" '. $file_parms, false, 'file') . '<br />' . $pInfo->products_image
                    );
                }
                $contents[] = array(
                    'text' => '<br /><strong>' . TEXT_MEDIUM_FILE_IMAGE . '</strong><br />' . zen_draw_input_field('medium_image', '', 'size="20" ' . $file_parms, false, 'file') . '<br />'
                );
                $contents[] = array(
                    'text' => '<br /><strong>' . TEXT_LARGE_FILE_IMAGE . '</strong><br />' . zen_draw_input_field('large_image', '', 'size="20" ' . $file_parms, false, 'file') . '<br />'
                );
                $contents[] = array(
                    'align' => 'center', 
                    'text' => '<br />' . zen_image_submit('button_save.gif', IMAGE_SAVE) 
                );
                break;



            default:
                $heading[] = array(
                    'text' => '<strong>' . TEXT_INFO_SELECT_ACTION . '</strong>'
                );
                $contents = array(
                    'align' => 'center', 
                    'form' => zen_draw_form('image_define', FILENAME_IMAGE_HANDLER, 'ih_page=' . $ih_page . '&amp;products_filter=' . $products_filter . '&amp;action=save', 'post', 'enctype="multipart/form-data"')
                );
                // show new, delete, and edit buttons
                $contents[] = array(
                    'align' => 'center', 
                    'text' => '<br />' .
                        ' <a href="' . $ih_admin->imageHandlerHrefLink($_GET['imgName'], $products_filter, 'layout_edit') . '">'
                        . zen_image_button('button_edit.gif', IH_IMAGE_EDIT) . '</a> &nbsp; '
                        . ' <a href="' . $ih_admin->imageHandlerHrefLink($_GET['imgName'], $products_filter, 'layout_delete') . '">'
                        . zen_image_button('button_delete.gif', IMAGE_DELETE) . '</a> &nbsp;'
                        . ' <a href="' . $ih_admin->imageHandlerHrefLink('', $products_filter, 'layout_new') . '">'
                        . zen_image_button('button_new_file.gif', IH_IMAGE_NEW_FILE) . '</a> &nbsp;'
                        . ' <input id="close-tooltip" type="button" value="Cancel" alt="Cancel" title="Cancel"/>'
                );
                $contents[] = array();
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, something like that would be simple enough, though I'd strongly recommend attaching separate listeners for separate functionalities rather than using `switch` once you migrate to JS

Comment: That's not a button it's a link.  And it may be helpful to see what the switch is on `switch(?)`  Javascript has it's own version of a switch statement.  If you want to move this whole thing to JS, the more important question is where do the variables come from.  If you want to keep it in PHP and call that file by AJAX then I would need to see more of the file.  But there is no technical reason you cant pick the case with a variable from AJAX, rather or not the page is designed in a way that will let you do that easily is another matter.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix. Agreed, it is a link. I referred to it as a button as that's how it appears to the end user. Any variables that are required for this code to run are passed by the script that calls the AJAX tooltip. I recall that it only needs the product id. The rest of the data is collected in an sql query earlier in the code. I've added the entire switch to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Don't really need the whole switch just this `$action`, which is what you need to change.  See there is no way to know without knowing where that comes from if its `$_POST['action']` or `$_GET['action']` it's no problem, follow.  If it's some session variable that comes from 3 files over after 2 sql queries, then who knows.

Comment: See it's in your button/link.  So change that to be not a link, and just call the url via AJAX instead.  `<a href="http://localhost/devarea/devadmin/image_handler.php?products_filter=313&amp;action=layout_edit">` right here `action=layout_edit`  AKA `$_GET['action']`

Comment: $action is just looking to see what "action" was appended to the url, example 'action=layout_edit' 
There is a small code section earlier in the file like 
$action = '';
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) { 
        $action = $_POST['action'];
    } elseif (isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $action = $_GET['action'];
    }

Comment: That's kind of stupid, lol,  `$_REQUST['action']` can replace that whole thing.  But anyway, that's still from the link.  `$.get('http://localhost/devarea/devadmin/image_handler.php?products_filter=313&action=layout_edit', function(data){ .... });` same thing.  I don't know what this stupid double encoded `&amp;` is in there for.

Comment: That's where I'm not sure of the process, because the file I would be calling via AJAX is the same file that is already loaded. ie, the tooltipster is loading product_image_ajax.php via AJAX, and the switch is currently also within product_image_ajax.php. 
Can you even do that?

Comment: Oh believe me, there is a huge amount of 'stupid' code in here! It's zen cart admin which doesn't seem to have been changed much since it was forked from osCommerce in 2003

Comment: You can't load a page by ajax, you call a page with ajax, and whatever it outputs get's returned to the callback.  Now rather or not it echos out what you need is another question.  There is no state maintained, it's just a request/response.  Same as putting that link in the URL of the browser it's not magic.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'll have a go and see where I get to

Comment: The web is simple, you have 2 kinds of requests, GET and POST, and one kind or return (String).  The string becomes something special by the headers, like image or a download, but it's all strings.  Get is the URL post is something else.  You can take a PHP file, set the header to image, read the content of the image out, and now the PHP file is an image.

Comment: I would just put this link in the browser url and see what it gives me back `http://localhost/devarea/devadmin/image_handler.php?products_filter=313&action=layout_edit`  Same as what that link does, same as what an AJAX call does, the server doesn't know the difference.